# Why was this question not automatically deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I was reading up on the difference between *whoever* and *whomever* today and came across a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/302859/112436) with zero net vote, and no answers.  I thought that the periodic automatic deletion process would delete such a question.  But it was dated January, 2016.  Why is it still there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimally? Because it's not closed, and because it hasn't been a year yet.

The exact automatic deletion criteria are complex.  See: [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

Comment: So the automatic deletion process isn't monthly, as I had understood, but yearly?  Okay.  I guess I'll go back there and vote to close.

Comment: [The criteria are complex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/153355).

Comment: Aha.  I will downvote to bring the question's net vote down to -1, and enable a quicker automatic deletion.  Thank you.

Comment: @aparente001 Voting on the usefulness of a question (or answer) is the single most important contribution, other than answering questions, that anybody can make to the site.

Comment: January 2016 to December 2017 is a bit more than a year....

Comment: @MetaEd And, of course, *asking* questions.

Comment: @Lawrence I look at it a little differently. SE exists to collect expert answers. Questions we have no shortage of. What people come here for is answers.